# Why does the order of the link elements in <head> matter?

Tags: html, css, syntax

From Code Academy's [Make a Website: CSS Styling](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-4lw13/0/6?content_from=make-a-website%3Acss-properties-box):

```
     <head>
         <link href="font.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    </head>
```

> "Inside the head element are two link elements. The order of these
>   link elements matters.
>
> > The browser first sees the link for the custom font font.css, and
> >     makes the font available to use in the page.
> >
> > Next the browser sees the link for main.css. Since the browser now
> >     knows about the custom font, we can use it from main.css to style
> >     elements."

I want to have an intuition/answer as to why does the order matter (link to fonts before the main CSS stylesheet)?

I tried to do it in the other order (link to main stylesheet before link to fonts) and it still worked.

Answer (score 11):

Order matters when you're overriding CSS definitions. This is part of the "cascade" of cascading style sheets. If `main.css` does not contain any font definitions, then the order doesn't matter.

For example: you were given a default CSS file from a designer, but you need to tweak it a little. Instead of editing the `default.css` file, you create a `custom.css` file and change only the handful of definitions that you wanted to tweak. Now the order matters.

```
<head>
    <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
```

If you were to put `custom.css` first, then your changes would never appear.

[Here's an article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) that gets into various levels of further detail. Warning, it can make your head spin.